# How to align text in mat-cell in Angular-Material

Tags: typescript, angular-material, material-design, materialize

Here, I am using Angular-Material for displaying the list of products in which I have flat json object. I have json as follows:

```
data: [
{
    "identifier": "data",
    "categoryId": "1",
    "category": "Baked goods",
    "product": "Aunt Hattie's",
    "price": "375"
},
{
    "identifier": "data",
    "categoryId": "1",
    "category": "Baked goods",
    "product": "Back to Nature",
    "price": "343"
},        
{
    "identifier": "data",
    "categoryId": "2",
    "category": "Cakes",
    "product": "Mars Muffin (McVitie's)",
    "price": "465"
},
{
    "identifier": "data",
    "categoryId": "2",
    "category": "Cakes",
    "product": "McVitie's",
    "price": "251"
},
{
    "identifier": "data",
    "categoryId": "2",
    "category": "Cakes",
    "product": "Mr Kipling",
    "price": "260"
},
{
    "identifier": "data",
    "categoryId": "2",
    "category": "Cakes",
    "product": "Mr Kipling Frosty Fancies",
    "price": "210"
},
{
    "identifier": "data",
    "categoryId": "3",
    "category": "Dairy products",
    "product": "Amul",
    "price": "474"
},
{
    "identifier": "data",
    "categoryId": "3",
    "category": "Dairy products",
    "product": "Borden",
    "price": "184"
},
{
    "identifier": "data",
    "categoryId": "3",
    "category": "Dairy products",
    "product": "Broughton Foods Company",
    "price": "43"
},
```

]

**Edited**
I am displaying this data like this :

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <!-- Product Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Product">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Product </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">  
      <div *ngIf="!HideShowCategory(element)"> 
          {{element.identifier}} <br/>
          {{element.categoryId}} <br/>
          {{element.category}} <br/>
      </div>
        {{element.product}} 
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Price Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Price">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Price </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.price}} </td>
  </ng-container>


  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

I am showing `identifier, category and product` in first column and `price` in second column in the **first row**. Row onwards for same `identifier, category` I am displaying only`product`.Because of which my cell height varies and of course because of that the price displaying in the next column seems to be the price of category. I want the `price` to be displayed in the bottom of the first row for same `identifier, category`. Please refer to the [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dltvqx?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html).

Everything seems perfect but the funny thing here is I am not been able to align the text inside the `mat-cell` at the bottom as my cell height varies from each other. I want to align text only when the cell height is greater than 50px

Comment: Can you create a working example for us to see?

Comment: @camden_kid I have updated in the question. Please refer to the working example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dltvqx?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using CSS - [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dltvqx-4kusi5?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html)

Markup

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <!-- Product Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Product">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Product </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">  
      <div *ngIf="!HideShowCategory(element)"> 
            {{element.identifier}} <br/>
            {{element.categoryId}} <br/>
            {{element.category}} <br/>
      </div>
         {{element.product}} 
      </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Price Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Price">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Price </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="price-container">
      <span [ngClass]="{'price-bottom': !HideShowCategory(element)}">{{element.price}}</span>
    </td>
  </ng-container>


  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
  width: 100%;
}

.price-container {
  position: relative;
}

.price-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

The idea is to make the Price position dependent on `HideShowCategory(element)`.

Comment: @IswarKChettri Glad it helps. It seemed the solution that required the least changes to your markup.